# Ionic Capacitor black screen after splash

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

After update to iOS 13 I've started to get a very strange black screen issue:
nothing has been changed inside the app's codebase;
when the app loads, I can inspect it with the Safari dev inspector, everything seem to work
no errors in my web inspector nor in the XCode console
app runs nicely on Android and in the browser

any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After iOS 13 update XCode adds the unseen property in the Info.plist, which essentially crashes the app:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```